# Return Alternating Letters in Two Strings of Different Lengths

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I currently have a code written that recursively takes the letters within two strings and returns the new word with alternating letters. I would like to optimize this code so that if the first or second word was longer it will still return the remaining letters in the longer string.

```
def alt(s,t):
    if len(s) != len(t):
        return 
    elif s == '' and t == '':
        return ''
    else:
        return s[0] + t[0] + alt(s[1:], t[1:])
```

Desired Output:

```
>>> alt('hello','bye')
'hbeylelo'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just test for `s` and `t` are empty and return the *other* value if one of them is:

```
def alt(s, t):
    if not s:
        return t
    elif not t:
        return s
    else:
        return s[0] + t[0] + alt(s[1:], t[1:])
```

Even if both `s` and `t` are empty, the empty string is returned, which is a perfectly valid end-state.

You could shorten this to:

```
def alt(s, t):
    if not (s and t):
        return s + t
    return s[0] + t[0] + alt(s[1:], t[1:])
```

so the end-state is reached whenever either `s` or `t` is empty (or they both are).

This produces your desired output:

```
>>> alt('hello', 'bye')
'hbeylelo'
```

An iterative version would be:

```
from itertools import chain
try:
    # Python 2
    from itertools import izip_longest as zip_longest
except ImportError:
    # Python 3
    from itertools import zip_longest

def alt_iterative(s, t):
    return ''.join(chain.from_iterable(zip_longest(s, t, fillvalue='')))
```

This uses the [`itertools.zip_longest()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to do most of the work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem itself is not inherently recursive. An iterative solution may be simpler in this case.

Python 2:

```
from itertools import izip_longest
def alt(s, t):
    return ''.join(a + b for a, b in izip_longest(s, t, fillvalue=''))
```

Python 3:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def alt(s, t):
    return ''.join(a + b for a, b in zip_longest(s, t, fillvalue=''))
```

Comment: The OP is using Python 3, not 2, so you'll get an import error here. `zip_longest` (and `izip_longest` in 2) take a `fillvalue` argument, just set that to `''`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Of course, thanks for the hints. Sometimes you don't see the wood for the trees.

Answer (score 0):

If you like a one-liner using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) (or [itertools.zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)/[izip_longest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)):

```
# Python 2
return ''.join(chain(*zip(s, t))) + s[len(t):] + t[len(s):]
# or
return ''.join(chain(*izip_longest(s, t, fillvalue='')))

# Python 3
return ''.join(chain(*zip_longest(s, t, fillvalue='')))
```

Comment: If you are using `itertools` already, why not use `itertools.zip_longest()` while you are at it?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Keeping it compatible with Python 2. I guess.